# Ethereum taken from MEW? Any way to trace owner?

Tags: transactions

can anyone help with this. I think somebody has stolen all my ether from my ether wallet. Their address on etherscan is here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4b03b72d8ce714b14efe4843170a219c02a3f5c2 and the 6.9547 Ether in is from my wallet. I haven’t done any transactions today so it can’t be a wallet on an exchange that I’ve forgotten about. Does anybody know what I can do about this?

Comment: Make sure you are using the official site `https://www.myetherwallet.com/` there are several scams sites that are copies with a slightly modified URL, check for "MYETHERWALLET LLC [US]" in the site certificate. If you think you are affected report your incident at https://etherscamdb.info/.